# Multiple forms in one JSP with Spring MVC 3

Tags: spring-mvc

Is it possible to have multiple forms on a single page using Spring MVC 3+ ?

I have this at the moment but when I call one of the method in the controller via its requestMapping, I get an error saying that the mapping to the second form doesn't exist.

This is the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean     name 'stockLoadingForm' available as request attribute
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put model attribute on spring form ?

```
<form:form id="stock" method="post" action="" modelAttribute="stockLoadingForm">
```

And if you are using older tomcat versions then you might face this issue even though you have include the model attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For each form we have to take different action names then we can write multiple forms ?
You can try